# Swift ignoring parameter types defined in block signature

Tags: swift, nspredicate, swift-block, swift-optionals

I have the code below, which the compiler is happy with:

```
func CheckPaintExists(colorCode : String, applicationCode : String) {
    let checkRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Paint")
    checkRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(block: { (item, bindings) -> Bool in
        return (item as! Paint).ColorCode == colorCode 
            && (item as! Paint).ApplicationCode == applicationCode
    })
    checkRequest.includesSubentities = false;

    //managedContext.count(for: ...)do further stuff
}
```

But once I define the `item` type in the block signature, I get an error on the return line:

```
func CheckPaintExists2(colorCode : String, applicationCode : String) {
    let checkRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Paint")
    checkRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(block: { (item : Paint?, bindings : NSDictionary?) -> Bool in
        return item.ColorCode == colorCode //*Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'ColorCode'
            && item.ApplicationCode == applicationCode
    })
    checkRequest.includesSubentities = false;

    //managedContext.count(for: ...)do further stuff
}
```

It says `Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'ColorCode'`. How can I resolve this? Why is it still using the default Any type provided by the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [signature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1416182-init) for `NSPredicate.init(block:)` then you will see that block takes two parameters and returns a boolean: `(Any?, [String : Any]?) -> Bool)` and the first parameter is indeed an `Any`.

In your first example you are force casting with `as!` which is why it works (it would crash here if the type was not actually `Paint` boxed in an `Any`.  Your second example is giving you an error because your type annotation is wrong; the compiler expects the first parameter to be `Any` and not `Paint?`; it really should be giving you the error on the line above but it seems its first catching it on the line with the return.

If you want to unwrap safely it should be:

```
func CheckPaintExists(colorCode : String, applicationCode : String) {
    let checkRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Paint")
    checkRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(block: { (item, bindings) -> Bool in
        guard let paint = item as? Paint else {
           return false
        }
        return paint.ColorCode == colorCode 
            && paint.ApplicationCode == applicationCode
    })
    checkRequest.includesSubentities = false;

    //managedContext.count(for: ...)do further stuff
}
```

Comment: What weird is that Xcode autocomplete/suggestions actually bring up/suggest the Paint properties when I hit `dot` on item. Meaning that it sees item as being of type Paint. Once I hit enter to place the property, it then complains. I just found that strange. I did think about safe unwrapping `item` but I thought to myself that surely I know `item` will be of type Paint, and safely unwrapping it just seemed cumbersome for my case.They say swift is less code than swift, I say its the opposite really. Thats a topic for another convo I guess. Cheers